# Defining date cycles in a table via a Boolean (PowerBI, Python)

Tags: python, powerbi, powerquery

Consider the following table consisting of a *Date* and *Item* column:

| Date | Item |
| --- | --- |
| April 2 | X |
| April 3 | X |
| April 5 | X |
| April 11 | X |
| April 12 | X |
| April 14 | X |
| April 20 | X |
| April 2 | Y |
| April 3 | Y |
| April 9 | Y |
| April 11 | Y |
| April 12 | Y |
| April 14 | Y |

I would like to add an additional column called *StartFlag* containing Boolean values that indicate if an item "entered" this list, and by "enter" we understand the following:

An item **"enters"** the list if it was not on the list for the past 5 days.

Hence, the above table should result in the following:

| Date | Item | StartFlag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| April 2 | X | TRUE |
| April 3 | X | FALSE |
| April 5 | X | FALSE |
| April 11 | X | TRUE |
| April 12 | X | FALSE |
| April 14 | X | FALSE |
| April 20 | X | TRUE |
| April 2 | Y | TRUE |
| April 3 | Y | FALSE |
| April 9 | Y | TRUE |
| April 11 | Y | FALSE |
| April 12 | Y | FALSE |
| April 14 | Y | FALSE |

Does someone have a solution for this problem in PowerBI? (I am able to run a Python script on my data so that could also lead to a solution.)

Thank you. -- JD

Comment: Do you want to do this in `DAX` or `PowerQuery`?

Comment: Hi, any kind of solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `DAX` solution. I've changed your data slightly, to use data in the full format.

### Table

| Date | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 02/04/2021 | X |
| 03/04/2021 | X |
| 05/04/2021 | X |
| 11/04/2021 | X |
| 12/04/2021 | X |
| 14/04/2021 | X |
| 20/04/2021 | X |
| 02/04/2021 | Y |
| 03/04/2021 | Y |
| 09/04/2021 | Y |
| 11/04/2021 | Y |
| 12/04/2021 | Y |
| 14/04/2021 | Y |

### Calculated Column

```
StartFlag =
VAR SelectedItem = [Item]
VAR SelectedDate = [Date]
VAR PreviousDate =
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', [Date] < SelectedDate && [Item] = SelectedItem ),
        [Date]
    )
VAR DateDifference = SelectedDate - PreviousDate
RETURN
    DateDifference >= 5
```

### Output

| Date | Item | StartFlag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02 April 2021 | X | True |
| 03 April 2021 | X | False |
| 05 April 2021 | X | False |
| 11 April 2021 | X | True |
| 12 April 2021 | X | False |
| 14 April 2021 | X | False |
| 20 April 2021 | X | True |
| 02 April 2021 | Y | True |
| 03 April 2021 | Y | False |
| 09 April 2021 | Y | True |
| 11 April 2021 | Y | False |
| 12 April 2021 | Y | False |
| 14 April 2021 | Y | False |

Comment: Would you be able to provide a PowerQuery solution as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `Power Query` solution. You can ignore the `Source` step, that's the data coming from `Enter Data` functionality.

### Steps

1. It's always good practice to Buffer a table that you will use multiple times, that's why `ToDate` is buffered.
2. The calculation starts at `AddCol`. Using `(row)` allows to access to each record. I took the idea from [here](https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2017/12/08/4270/power-query-m-primer-part3-functions-function-values-passing-returning-defining-inline-recursion).
3. With `Table.SelectRows` we filter the table from the previous step, retrieving the max date excluding the current record date.
4. Finally we do a subtraction between the two columns and convert the output into a number with `Number.From`. This is evaluated in an `IF` statement.

### Calculation

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(
    Json.Document(
      Binary.Decompress(
        Binary.FromText(
          "Zc6xCQAgDETRXVILJlELNzGI+6+hhYXy2wd3/DlFPWvNrm6SZMhKhwqpgcxI/LIKcuX9OwxGXOqgLyIYEYw4tDY=",
          BinaryEncoding.Base64
        ),
        Compression.Deflate
      )
    ),
    let
      _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
    in
      type table [Date = _t, Item = _t]
  ),
  ToDate = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Date", type date}}),
  BufferedToDate = Table.Buffer(ToDate),
  AddCol = Table.AddColumn(
    BufferedToDate,
    "StartFlag",
    (row) =>
      let
        PreviousDate = List.Max(
          Table.SelectRows(BufferedToDate, each [Date] < row[Date] and [Item] = row[Item])[Date]
        ),
        IfStatement = Number.From(
          if PreviousDate = null then row[Date] else row[Date] - PreviousDate
        )
      in
        IfStatement >= 5
  )
in
  AddCol
```

### Output

| Date | Item | StartFlag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/04/2021 | X | TRUE |
| 03/04/2021 | X | FALSE |
| 05/04/2021 | X | FALSE |
| 11/04/2021 | X | TRUE |
| 12/04/2021 | X | FALSE |
| 14/04/2021 | X | FALSE |
| 20/04/2021 | X | TRUE |
| 02/04/2021 | Y | TRUE |
| 03/04/2021 | Y | FALSE |
| 09/04/2021 | Y | TRUE |
| 11/04/2021 | Y | FALSE |
| 12/04/2021 | Y | FALSE |
| 14/04/2021 | Y | FALSE |